# Kafka Authentication with SASL - duplicate admin user?

Tags: apache-kafka, jaas, sasl

I'm running a distributed Kafka-Broker where the inter-broker-communication is set up with SASL/SSL. For this I adapted the JAAS-Configuration given [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authentication_sasl/index.html). The finished file looks like this:

```
KafkaServer {
  org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
  username="admin"
  password="admin-secret"
  user_admin="admin-secret"
  user_alice="alice-secret"
  security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
  sasl.mechanism=PLAIN;

  org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required;
};

Client {
  org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
  username="admin"
  password="admin-secret";
};
```

I noticed that the "KafkaServer"-section has 2 admin users. I also learned the hard way that I need both, but why is that? I have the feeling I've read (and forgot) the reason a few months ago, but I can't seem to find it anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the [Apache Kafka documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_jaas_broker), the `KafkaServer` section is used to configure authentication *from* this broker to other brokers, as well as for clients and other brokers connecting *to* this broker.  The `Client` section is used for connecting to Zookeeper.

Since your question is about the `KafkaServer` section, and you are configuring a SASL/PLAIN authentication mechanism, refer to [this part](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_sasl_plain_brokerconfig) of the Apache Kafka documentation:

> This configuration defines two users (*admin* and *alice*). The properties `username` and `password` in the `KafkaServer` section are used by the broker to initiate connections to other brokers. In this example, *admin* is the user for inter-broker communication. The set of properties `user_userName` defines the passwords for all users that connect to the broker and the broker validates all client connections including those from other brokers using these properties.

In other words, there are two separate cases configured here:

- *When this broker connects out to other brokers* it will use the username and password defined in `username` and `password`.
- *When clients and other brokers connect to this broker*, the `user_userName` entries are used to authenticate these connections, where the username is the *userName* part of the `user_userName` key, and the password is the value.

So, in your example, this broker will connect to other brokers with a username of `admin` and a password of `admin-secret` because of these two lines:

```
username="admin"
password="admin-secret"
```

And, clients and other brokers can connect to this broker either with the username password combo of `admin` / `admin-secret` or `alice` / `alice-secret` because of these two lines:

```
user_admin="admin-secret"
user_alice="alice-secret"
```

If you only are accepting connections from other brokers for inter-broker communication on this listener, they probably are using the `user_admin="admin-secret"` part of the configuration, and the `user_alice="alice-secret"` probably is superfluous.

Comment: Well this confirms my suspicion. And the quoted part even is the one I read before but didn't manage to find anymore. Thank you very much :)